# Post building react-snap is throwing error "EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir"

Tags: reactjs, prerender, react-snap

I have installed `react-snap` version **"^1.23.0"** and attached postbuild script **"react-snap"** and ran `npm run build`. It did crawl most of the pages and after completing last but one page, it showed the above error. Does it have any other dependencies like NodeJS version or react-scripts version?

```
NodeJS - 12.13.1
react-scripts - 3.4.1
```

Comment: hi. did you find any solutions for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Hey, it was just my POC part, so I moved on. I had an alternative to work around which is gatsby. Gatsby resolved every single use case I had, mostly SEO.